# Special Character in UserName for iPhone app

Tags: ios, objective-c

Have some special character in username like tüser, when i try to add it into NSMutableDictionary it is adding in a different format. Let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: How do you store it in the dictionary? And show the format in question.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with different format? If you are using NSLog to print the content of dictionary, you might see it escape some special characters, but you'll still be able to access the value using that key.

```
NSMutableDictionary * dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dictionary setObject: @"hello" forKey: @"tüser"];
NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", dictionary);
NSLog(@"Value: %@", [dictionary objectForKey: @"tüser"]);
```

Output:

> Dictionary: {
>       "t\U00fcser" = hello; }
>
> Value: hello